# How to retrieve array in php sent from iOS

Tags: php, ios, web-services, nsmutablearray

Following is my iOS code that sends NSmutable Array to PHP webservice:

```
 // Getting Server Address
            AppDelegate *appDelegate =
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

            NSString *serverAddress = [appDelegate getServerAddress];

            serverAddress = [serverAddress stringByAppendingString:@"ABC.php"];


            NSLog(@"Server Address: %@",serverAddress);

            NSData *post = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:UsersArray options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
            NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [post length]];
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:serverAddress]];

            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [request setHTTPBody:post];
            [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
            [request setTimeoutInterval:30];
            NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
            [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse* theResponse, NSData* theData, NSError* error){
                //Do whatever with return data

                NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:theData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"Result : %@",result);
            }];
```

I want to retrive that array in PHP. How can I do that?

Here is the php which I tried but returns null:

```
$handle = fopen('php://input','r');
$jsonInput = fgets($handle);
// Decoding JSON into an Array
$decoded = json_decode($jsonInput,true);

echo json_encode($decoded);
```

Comment: What does the log show?

Comment: Seems your method is post. Try checking the values you got using `print_r($_POST);` on php side.

Comment: Here is link for a good tutorial [how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app) Johan

Comment: print_r($_POST) returns "Result : Array
(
)
1"

Comment: but I think it doesn't send NSMutable Array to webservice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a slightly different `Content-Type` (which shouldn't matter):

```
[request addValue:@"text/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

And I use a slightly different PHP, too:

```
<?php

$handle = fopen("php://input", "rb");
$http_raw_post_data = '';
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $http_raw_post_data .= fread($handle, 8192);
}
fclose($handle); 

$json_data = json_decode($http_raw_post_data, true);

echo json_encode($json_data);

?>
```

If you're getting a blank response, I'd wager you have some PHP error. I'd you check out your server's error log, or temporarily changing the `display_errors` setting in your php.ini as follows:

```
display_errors = On
```

Comment: $http_raw_post_data is an Array. Right?

Comment: When I do $json_data = json_decode($http_raw_post_data[0], true); in order to send first index value it returns null.

Comment: So How can I convert in PHP Array?

Comment: @ChampTaurus The `$http_raw_post_data` is the raw data. The `$json_data` is the array that was converted to an array by `json_decode`.

Comment: Oh yeah I got it. Thanks alot. You have solved my time consuming problem :)