# send zip file from ios app to php server

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, xampp, nsdata

I am building a client-server app in which the app is sending a zip file that contains a lot of images and the php server should check if the file was received and returns the number of the images in the zip file that was sent.

here is my code in the app:

```
        NSData *zipData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:zipFile]; // zipFile contains the zip file path

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [zipData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/test.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:zipData];

    NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;
    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];
    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response Code: %d", [urlResponse statusCode]);

    if ([urlResponse statusCode] >= 200 && [urlResponse statusCode] < 300)
    {
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", result);
    }
```

and here is my php file that runs on local host using xampp:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);

print_r($_FILES);
?>
```

the zip file is attached to the request using sethttpbody, I am trying to view the file in the php as shown above but it is always empty, please help me with that , moreover is that right to see the sent zip file by printing the $_POST and $_FILES if not what is the right way to do that, the zip file is converted to NSDATA, also I have checked that the connection is established but I am really confused with this.

Comment: What did your PHP script return? Can you show that response? Did you check basics as max post size, memory limit and the likes in your php.ini ?

Comment: @Rob I did not understand the example and what is the wrong with what I have done so far , I have constructed the request to be application/x-www-form-urlencoded, can you give me simple php that checks if the server got the zip file ,thanks in advance.

Comment: @ToBe there is no problem with max post size and memory limits and the  the response that I get : 2013-11-20 15:47:29.824 storyboardGui[55406:1116b] Response Code: 200
2013-11-20 15:47:29.825 storyboardGui[55406:1116b] Response: (null)

Comment: Your response (3rd comment) indicates that PHP did not return anything, not even the two potentially empty arrays. I suspect that your problem is something completely different. Please make sure that your PHP actually get's called! Maybe write debugging info to a file if you have trouble showing PHPs response in your client app.

Comment: @ToBe , I am sorry I really get two empty arrays but why is that happening, it should show the name of the zip file is not that right?!

Comment: It should show the ZIP file (and some other info) as $_FILES, but only if you did set your form encoding right. Did you check if normal $_POST variables are visible?

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with your Objective-C code, in which you define your `Content-Type` header as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but then the body of the request is not consistent with that `Content-Type`. You can, theoretically, write PHP code that handles the request as constructed (read the raw data of the body), but it's probably better to change the request to conform to established standards.

If you write the code to construct such a request yourself, it's a little ugly (see the end of this answer), so I'd suggest using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), which greatly simplifies the creation of such requests:

```
NSData *zipData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:zipFile];
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager POST:urlString parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:zipData name:@"file" fileName:[zipFile lastPathComponent] mimeType:@"application/zip"];
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    BOOL success = [responseObject[@"success"] boolValue];
    NSString *errorMessage = responseObject[@"error"];
    NSLog(@"Success: %d; Error message: %@", success, errorMessage);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Note, this expects a JSON response, so the corresponding PHP code to receive it, save it into an "upload" subdirectory, and return JSON response might look like:

```
<?php

    header("Content-Type: application/json");

    $allowedExts = array("zip", "gz");
    $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
    if (in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
    {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
            echo json_encode(array("success" => false, "error" => $_FILES["file"]["error"]));
        }
        else
        {
            if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
            {
                echo json_encode(array("success" => false, "error" => $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists"));
            }
            else
            {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                echo json_encode(array("success" => true));
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo json_encode(array("success" => false, "error" => "Invalid file type"));
    }

?>
```

---

While I'd really encourage you to use AFNetworking, if you want to construct your own request, you could do something like:

```
[self uploadFileAtPath:zipFile forField:@"file" URL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] parameters:nil completion:^(BOOL success, NSString *errorMessage) {
    NSLog(@"success = %d; errorMessage = %@", success, errorMessage);
}];
```

Where, `uploadFileAtPath` and some supporting methods are defined like so:

```
- (void)uploadFileAtPath:(NSString *)path
                forField:(NSString *)fieldName
                     URL:(NSURL*)url
              parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
              completion:(void (^)(BOOL success, NSString *errorMessage))completion
{
    NSString *filename = [path lastPathComponent];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

    NSMutableData *httpBody = [NSMutableData data];
    NSString *boundary = [self generateBoundaryString];
    NSString *mimetype = [self mimeTypeForPath:path];

    // configure the request

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
    [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:30];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    // set content type

    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    // add params (all params are strings)

    [parameters enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *parameterKey, NSString *parameterValue, BOOL *stop) {
        [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", parameterKey] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", parameterValue] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }];

    // add image data

    if (data) {
        [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", fieldName, filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: %@\r\n\r\n", mimetype] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [httpBody appendData:data];
        [httpBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }

    [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // setting the body of the post to the reqeust

    [request setHTTPBody:httpBody];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        if (connectionError)
        {
            if (completion)
                completion(FALSE, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s: sendAsynchronousRequest error: %@", __FUNCTION__, connectionError]);
            return;
        }

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSDictionary *responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
        if (!responseObject)
        {
            if (completion)
                completion(FALSE, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s: JSONObjectWithData error=%@", __FUNCTION__, error]);
            return;
        }

        BOOL success = [responseObject[@"success"] boolValue];
        NSString *errorMessage = responseObject[@"error"];
        if (completion)
            completion(success, errorMessage);
    }];
}

- (NSString *)generateBoundaryString
{
    // generate boundary string
    //
    // adapted from http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleURLConnections
    //
    // Note in iOS 6 and later, you can just:
    //
    //    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Boundary-%@", [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]];

    CFUUIDRef  uuid;
    NSString  *uuidStr;

    uuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    assert(uuid != NULL);

    uuidStr = CFBridgingRelease(CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuid));
    assert(uuidStr != NULL);

    CFRelease(uuid);

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Boundary-%@", uuidStr];
}

- (NSString *)mimeTypeForPath:(NSString *)path
{
    // get a mime type for an extension using MobileCoreServices.framework

    CFStringRef extension = (__bridge CFStringRef)[path pathExtension];
    CFStringRef UTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, extension, NULL);
    assert(UTI != NULL);

    NSString *mimetype = CFBridgingRelease(UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(UTI, kUTTagClassMIMEType));
    assert(mimetype != NULL);

    CFRelease(UTI);

    return mimetype;
}
```

Comment: I dont want to use this way ,what is the wrong with my posted code?

Comment: @user2960510 Both the `$_POST` and the `$_FILES` server variables require that the request be well-formed HTTP `POST` request for the server to parse it. You cannot just put the `NSData` of your zip file in the body and then hope to use `$_POST` or `$_FILES`. That won't work. For example, how is your server going to know the name of the file being uploaded or the field name to use in the `$_POST` array? You could theoretically use PHP `fopen` (e.g. a variant of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17023318/1271826)) to get the raw data, but I wouldn't recommend that for uploading zip files.

Comment: @user2960510 I'd be inclined to use the I'd suggest either the above, or create a JSON request where you base 64 encode the binary data (and then handle the JSON request as outlined [in that other post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17023318/1271826)) and then have your PHP perform the `base64_decode` to get the binary data back out.

Comment: I need to use only httprequest without JSON , can you explain what shoul I do? thanks

Comment: can you define what is a well-formed HTTP? and how to change my code to support using the variable $_POST ? thanks

Comment: @user2960510 I've provided another answer that shows you how you could write PHP to handle your current request format for which the `HTTPBody` is just the zip data (but I don't think much of that implementation). For what constitutes a well-formed HTTP `multipart/form-data` request for which your server can access the `$_POST` values, see the rather dense [RFC 2388](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt), which my code above attempts to construct. Or use JSON.

Answer (score 1):

While I wouldn't recommend it (I'd prefer to see a well-formed `multipart/form-data` or `application/JSON` request), you could create your request like so:

```
NSData *zipData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:zipFile]; // note, autorelease object

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [zipData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/zip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:zipData];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    NSString *result = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

    NSInteger statusCode = -1;
    if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]])
        statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];

    NSLog(@"Response Code: %d", statusCode);

    if (statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 300)
    {
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", result);
    }
}];
```

And then you could have PHP code that reads this binary data and saves it to a file:

```
<?php

$handle = fopen("php://input", "rb");
$http_raw_post_data = '';
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $http_raw_post_data .= fread($handle, 8192);
}
fclose($handle);

$handle = fopen('upload/myzip.zip', 'wb');

if ($handle == false) {
    echo 'unable to open file';
    exit (0);
}

$bytes = fwrite($handle, $http_raw_post_data);

if ($bytes == false)
    echo 'write failed';
else
    echo 'write succeeded';

fclose($handle);

?>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, I appreciate your help but can you explain what does the php code do? beacuse the zip file contains imajes what does that mean to read the file , does it read each image every time?!

Comment: @user2960510 All this PHP code does is grab the raw data of the request and write it to a file. That's it. No file names. No ability to add additional parameters to the request. Just "grab the raw data and save it." Neither this, nor my other answer about `multipart/form-data` do anything with the zip file other than saving it as a single zip file. If you want to search the zip for the names of the images, you have to write the code to do that yourself (using the [PHP zip functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.zip.php)).